# How do I append a child node to an existing parent node passed to a function?

Tags: xml, matlab, function, append

I have placed the same question on the Mathworks site.

I am trying to send an xml structure to a function, append a new node, and return the modified structure. This is because the child structure being appended will be very common to many '.xml' files and I don't want to re-write the same code every time.

If I am not in a function the following works:

```
   docNode = com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('ugcs-Transfer');
   parent_node = docNode.createElement('parent')
   docNode.appendChild(parent_node)
   child_node = docNode.createElement('child');
   parent_node.appendChild(child_node);
```

If I try to pass it to a function like this:

```
   docNode = com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('ugcs-Transfer');
   parent_node = docNode.createElement('parent')
   docNode.appendChild(parent_node)
   docNode = myFunction(docNode)
```

This function will not append the child to the parent node:

```
Z = my_function(docNode)
    child_node = docNode.createElement('child');
    parent_node.appendChild(child_node);  % This line produces an error:
    %Undefined variable "parent_node" or ...
    %class "parent_node.appendChild".
    Z = docNode
end
```

The desired end state would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <parent>
        <child>
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with the syntax. I will only give a short example since the other child nodes are following the same pattern. Note that the `docNode` actually is just this, the document. MATLAB uses Apaches xerxes DOM model and the function `createDocument()` returns an object of type `org.apache.xerces.dom.CoreDocumentImpl`. You do not append to the document, but rather to the document elements (`org.apache.xerces.dom.ElementImpl`). So you need get the document element first. Do not be bothered about the `Impl` part. This is just because there are interfaces defined in `org.w3c.dom` which have to be to be implemented and the `Impl` is just an implementation of these interfaces.

```
docNode = com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('ugcs-Transfer');
parent_node_elem = docNode.getDocumentElement(); % Append to this and not docNode.
parent_node = docNode.createElement('parent');
parent_node_elem.appendChild(parent_node);
xmlwrite(docNode);
```

This also works using subfunctions,

```
function test()
docNode = com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('ugcs-Transfer');
docNode = subfun(docNode);
q=xmlwrite(docNode);
disp(q);

function T = subfun(docNode)
parent_node_elem = docNode.getDocumentElement(); % Append to this and not docNode.
parent_node = docNode.createElement('parent');
parent_node_elem.appendChild(parent_node);
T = parent_node_elem;
```

You can also define a function which adds children to the current document element. To be able to add child by child you need to return the added child each time. Otherwise you will have to do an element search to find the element, which might be wanted sometimes, but for most of the cases this is annoying. Note that this is Java code so references are working here.

```
function test()
docNode = com.mathworks.xml.XMLUtils.createDocument('ugcs-Transfer');
parent_node = docNode.getDocumentElement();
parent_node = subfun(docNode, parent_node,'parent');
parent_node = subfun(docNode, parent_node,'child');
q=xmlwrite(docNode);
disp(q);

function T = subfun(docNode, elemNode, name)
child_node = docNode.createElement(name);
elemNode.appendChild(child_node);
T = child_node; % Return the newly added child.
```

If you want to to keep the references to the parents, then you can just define new variables each function call.

A longer example with attributes and all can be seen on the [`xmlwrite` reference page](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xmlwrite.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. A colleague provided another means of doing this:                              parent_node=docNode1.getElementsByTagName('Parent').item(0)

Comment: @Paul_Sponagle right, this is definitely possible. I see this as annoying and does actually prefer recursive methods for this kind of stuff (which this is not). However, it is definitly possible to do it your way as well (and sometimes it must be done that way). Just keep in mind that each parent can have multiple children and then you need to do a search among all the children and all will be fine. Further, even if you return the child you do not have to use it, but in case you _want_ to use it you will be really happy that you can.